Did black Americans make up 55.9% of known murder offenders in 2019?
The White Nationalist site VDARE claimed in a 2020 blog article:

The FBI has released its national crime stats for 2019. Murder was down 0.2%.
While blacks made up 52.5% of known murder offenders from 1980–2008, their percentage continues to inch upwards, reaching 55.9% in 2019


Do you just one a true/ false answer on this specific number (which can hopefully be found somewhere in the national crime stats) or some context, like say the population break down by ethnicity over time or the per year statistics to disentangle this strange x-y years versus a single year comparison?

What is a known murder offender? Is it someone who has been accused of murder? Arrested for murder? Convicted of murder?

@JoeW "based solely on police investigation as opposed to the determination of a court, medical examiner, coroner, jury, or other judicial body"

@DavePhD What exactly is that supposed to mean? And that should be in the question. It sounds like you are talking about being accused of murder which doesn't sound like a valuable statistic.

@JoeW It;'s not my question.  I don't think it requires being accused.  For example, if there is a video that clearly shows the murder and the race of the murder, but the identity of the murder is unknown so no one can be accused, then I think that would be included.

@DavePhD If it isn't your question and you are not sure why are you responding with that in a comment?

@JoeW because your question wasn't addressed to a particular person.

@DavePhD It was addressed to the OP, I didn't think there was a need to spell out that when I am asking for clarification on a question that I am asking the OP and not other random person who may or may not have posted an answer on the question.

@JoeW Not all murders are or can be prosecuted. Common cases are murder-suicide or where the murderer is killed by police action, like an active shooter. The offender cannot be found legally guilty, or even charged with murder, as you cannot criminally prosecute the dead. A second issue is murder cases easily can take several years to resolve, and people don't want to wait that long to see trends.

@user71659 Are you really suggesting that the number of cases of murder suicide are really that common? And even then just because someone is accused of being the murder doesn't mean that they actually are.

@JoeW And you're hand-waving and saying it's not? You're saying that most mass murder cases should not be counted because the police shot the perpetrator dead? Your proposal of legal murder convictions is definitely a wrong metric, simply because you ignore everybody who dies during the process.

@user71659 Now you are suggesting that most suspects are shot dead? Or are you suggesting that most suspects are mass murder cases? I am not suggesting any sort of legal definition, just that when looking at statistics it might not get the best results if you just look at who is accused.

@JoeW Nope. I believe a statistically significant number of suspects kill themselves, or are shot dead, or they die before they exhaust all appeals and the conviction is vacated. Common sense: most != statistically significant.

@JoeW: The question of definitions is not for the OP to resolve. We should look to the claimant. In this case, the claimant has explicitly stated their source, so it is reasonable to go to that source to find the definitions. If the definition is misleading to the lay public, feel free to mention that in an answer that addresses the question.

@user71659: Be wary of the term "statistically significant". It has a different meaning to "significant" (which seems the way you are using it).

@Oddthinking I didn’t say it was only up to the ozone to define, I just object to others making a guess about what something means. If you are not sure enough to edit it into the question why make a guess in the first place?

@JoeW: It wasn't a guess. The quote comes from the 2019 FBI National Crime Stats referenced in the question. Editing in the question would be a good idea if lots of people have the same confusion; not sure if that is the case or not.

@Oddthinking It sure seemed like a guess based on the response they gave me when I asked for more details and suggested it should be in the question.

@user71659 "Statistical significance is a mathematical measurement of the difference between groups. It's a measure of whether a result is likely due to chance or to some factor of interest" It doesn't mean that it is a large number of a group rather that the results are unlikely to change. If there really is a large number of people who kill themselves, or are shot/killed, or die before a conviction happens that would be big news. And note I have been talking about accused which is different then convicted and appealing the conviction.

@JoeW FBI stats show murder-suicides to be significantly more white than the average. These aren't and cannot be charged. Your faulty convictions measure would skew the numbers.

@user71659 You seem to be missing the point I am making, I don't care about who makes up the people that commit murder-suicides, I am suggesting that the numbers that those occur in are not that significant to begin with and are unlikely to have any sort of impact on the numbers in question. That article suggests there are under 600 of these a year which isn't much

@JoeW Your proposal 100% supports what I'm saying and importantly what the FBI is doing. You said "I have been talking about accused". FBI literally is attributing murders to who the police blame, regardless if they can be convicted or not, and not using convictions. You're running in circles.

@user71659 Incorrect, I am saying that just looking at the numbers of accused is likely going to give you bad numbers as it doesn't mean that they will actually be convicted of it (I don't care if it is later overturned). You need to consider both the numbers of accused and convicted to get a more accurate picture. There is plenty of evidence out there to suggest that who gets accused is influenced by race.

The FBI 2019 Expanded Homicide Data Table 3 says that of 16,245 "murder offenders":
4,728 were White
6,425 were Black
340 were Other [superscript 2:  Includes American Indian or Alaska Native, Asian, and Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander]
4,752 were Unknown
So it is true that the FBI reported that 55.9% of the murder offenders whose race is known to the FBI were Black.
Also, the FBI expressly states:

When the race of the offender was known, 55.9 percent were Black or African American, 41.1 percent were White, and 3.0 percent were of other races.


your answer does not match the footnote AT ALL. The footnote says "Not all agencies provide ethnicity data; therefore, the race and ethnicity totals will not equal"
The FBI data consists of race (white, black, other, unknown) as one category , and ethnicity as another. ethnicity is hispanic/latino, non-hispanic/latino, and unknown.
For race, 'unknown' means just that (e.g., unsolved). For ethnicity it means 'unknown' or not recorded.
Nothing here implies for a single teeny tiny moment that anyone is 'unwilling to share'

@thelawnet ok, I'll delete that part
